# Choosing which elements to replace in Python

Tags: python, replace

When I use the replace function I can input an additional 3rd argument which describes how many occurences of the particular character I might want to change.

For Example -

```
input_string = input()
first_char = input_string[0]
modified_string = input_string.replace(first_char, "$", input_string.count(first_char)-1)
print(modified_string)
```

The above code gives the following output:

```
Input: heyhhdh
Output: $ey$$dh
```

It replaced the h starting from the first occurrence but is there a way where I can specify where to start?

For instance in the problem I'm working on I need to leave the first character so is there a way to specify that in python

Edit:
The following line of code commented by [Tarique](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3116077/tarique) performs my task

```
modified_string = first_char + input_string[1:].replace(first_char, "$", input_string.count(first_char)-1)
```

However is there a way to do this using only string functions like modifying the arguments in the replace function?

Comment: You always want to skip the first char in your string? Do you want it to only replace starting at the second char and beyond? Or are more cases? @FoundABetterName

Comment: modified_string =  first_char + input_string[1:].replace(first_char, "$", input_string.count(first_char)-1)

Comment: i always want to skip the first char and use all others @Tarique

Comment: the comment i made above should do the trick, im not sure if there is a string function that will let you do that.

Comment: the code you provided works well in my case thanks :) however is there a way to not use this method and rather use only the replace function and it's arguments?  I've added this in the question too @Tarique

Comment: i'm not sure, but slicing is very useful, might help for you to read https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-slice-usage/

Comment: will check it out thanks @Tarique

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224707/discussion-between-foundabettername-and-tarique).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do what you already got, except without the pointless counting:

```
>>> first_char + input_string[1:].replace(first_char, '$')
'hey$$d$'
```

A single `replace` without anything else can't do it, but *two* can:

```
>>> input_string.replace(first_char, '$').replace('$', first_char, 1)
'hey$$d$'
```

That's only *two* linear-time operations instead of three, and for longer strings it's faster. For `input_string = 'hey$$d$' * 10**6` the first way takes me 12.1 ms and the second way takes me 9.4 ms.

A third but silly and slow (30.9 ms) way, simulating backwards-replacing by reversing the string before and after:

```
>>> input_string[::-1].replace(first_char, '$', input_string.count(first_char) - 1)[::-1]
'hey$$d$'
```

Answer (score 0):

Tarique's method is going to be the only way involving the replace method. You can specify the maximum number of characters to replace (see the bottom of [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) python documentation page), but that is the opposite of what you want. This is the same for Python 3, as seen [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/string_replace.htm).